# I have question about key bindings for emacs in OS X. Ask in emacs stack exchange? Or not?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about key bindings for emacs in OS X.  Is the emacs stack exchange an appropriate place to it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but please search the site first - there are a lot of questions here already about key bindings, your answer might be waiting for you!